# Rationals as an countable intersection of open sets

Tags: real-analysis

I understand that the rationals cannot be written as a countably infinite intersection of open sets.

I made a construction, though, and it seems from the construction that the rationals can be written as a countably infinite intersection of open sets. I don't know where I made an error. Please help!

Let $ q \in \mathbb{Q} $ and $ A_{qn} = B(q,\frac{1}{n}) $ where $ B(q,\frac{1}{n}) $ is the open ball of radius 1/n centered at q.

Let $ C_{n} = \bigcup\limits _{q\in\mathbb{Q}} A_{qn}$

Let $D = \bigcap\limits _{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}$

It seems that $D$ is equal to the rationals. If q is a rational, then it will be in D. If x is an element in D, then it seems that it ends up being a rational. Let me know where I went wrong!

Comment: Isn't $C_n=\Bbb R$ for all $n$?

Comment: "it seems that it ends up being a rational" is not a rigorous proof.

Comment: Your idea doesn't work for the rationals, but it's how you would prove the true statement, that every ***closed*** set of real numbers is a countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: Thank you Bungo; I mistakenly wrote "uncountable". I changed it to "countable"

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ then by density there is a rational $q$ in $(x,x+\frac{1}{2n})$, so $x\in A_{qn}$.

So $C_n=\Bbb R$.